# Запрос к представлению (view)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Есть бд `sqlite` где несколько таблиц и одно представление. Так собственно какой конструкцией задать запрос к представлению? Да и вообще возможно ли такое?

Comment: о чем вопрос? нет никакой конкретики

Comment: Да так же как и к таблицам, select-ом.